# Problema como jogo da forca em Python

Tags: python

Estou fazendo um jogo da forca em Python, o usuário escreve a palavra e depois a dica, outro usuário vai jogar o jogo e pode escolher entre jogar ou pedir uma dica mas na hora de retornar a dica da variável ela não printa e pula pra próxima pergunta, como posso recuperar a variavel para dentro do while

```
while dicas > 0:
menu = input("Digite 1 para Jogar ou 2 para Solicitar dica: ")
if(menu == 1):
    letra = str.lower(input("Digite uma letra: "))

    for i in range(0, len(palavra)):
        if letra == palavra[i]:
            letras_descobertas[i] = letra
            errou = False


    print(letras_descobertas)
    for x in range(0, len(letras_descobertas)):
        if letras_descobertas[x] == "*":
            acertou = False

    if errou == True:
        vida = vida -1
        print("Você errou! Você possui ", vida, "vidas.")

        if vida <= 0:
            print("Suas vidas acabaram!")
           
if(menu == 2):
    if(dica1 == str):
        print(dica1)
        dica1 = 0
    elif(dica2 == str):
        print(dica2)
        dica2 = 0
    elif(dica3 == str):
        print(dica3)
        dica3 = 0
dicas = dicas -1
```

código completo aqui (https://pastebin.com/print/WSs4dLGL)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O input sempre retorna um string vc deve ultilizar um int() para converter pra inteiro, com isso se torna comparavel;
Fora isso sempre que vc acertava uma letra 1º e dps errava ele não dava erro uma vez que a variavel Errou não teve seu valor voltado pra True, o coloquei no comeco do while; tbm o dicas = dicas -1 estava com erro de identação. Eu tbm n entendi o str, alem que não funcionava, nas dicas então coloquei de outra forma.

```
while dicas > 0:
errou = True
menu = int(input("Digite 1 para Jogar ou 2 para Solicitar dica: "))
if(menu == 1):
    letra = str.lower(input("Digite uma letra: "))

    for i in range(0, len(palavra)):
        if letra == palavra[i]:
            letras_descobertas[i] = letra
            errou = False


    print(letras_descobertas)
    for x in range(0, len(letras_descobertas)):
        if letras_descobertas[x] == "*":
            acertou = False

    if errou == True:
        vida = vida -1
        print("Você errou! Você possui ", vida, "vidas.")

        if vida <= 0:
            print("Suas vidas acabaram!")
            
if(menu == 2):
    if(dicas == 3):
        print(dica1)
        dica1 = 0
    elif(dicas == 2):
        print(dica2)
        dica2 = 0
    elif(dicas == 1):
        print(dica3)
        dica3 = 0
    dicas = dicas -1
```